# Scala regex split by multiple spaces and new line

Tags: regex, scala, split, io

I went through different regex documents for this but I'm still not getting it. I hope someone will be able to help me.

I have a table like this:

```
program     1  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
stmt_list   2  0  2  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  3
stmt        4  0  5  6  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

I want to read it from file and store in an array. I did the following:

```
val source = io.Source.fromFile("file.txt").getLines.toList.mkString.split("\\W+")
```

And I'm getting output like:

```
program
1
0
1
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1stmt_list // this is problem, int and string together which I don't want.
2
0
2
2
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
3stmt
4
0
.
.
.
```

I learned `\s` matches any space, tab or newline character. But when I tried, I'm getting error on scala `error: invalid escape character` . I tried bunch of other steps: `" +"`, `/\W+/` etc. None is working. I would highly appreciate any help. My goal is to read the file into a 2D array with only string and int values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem isn't so much the Regex itself, but the fact that you "merge" all the lines into one String (using `mkString`) instead of operating on each line separately, using `map`:

```
val source = Source.fromFile("file.txt")
  .getLines.toList             // gets a list of file lines
  .map(_.split("\\W+").toList) // maps each line into a list

source.foreach(println)
// List(program, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
// List(stmt_list, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3)
// List(stmt, 4, 0, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: I guess you don't need the middle .toList :)

Comment: True, although that depends on what you want to do with that result - without that `toList`, `source` has type `Iterator[List[String]]` - good for most purposes, specifically won't change the result of `source.foreach(..)`, but it's needed if you know you need a `List[List[String]]`.